# Yii2 set scenario is not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am want to add extra fields to one of my action using scenario for my rest application. This is what I did 

 Controller action

```
$model =(new Job(['scenario' => Job::SCENARIO_MORE]))->findOne(['id'=>$id]);
if ($model){
    return $model;
}
```

Model code

```
const SCENARIO_LESS = 'index';
const SCENARIO_MORE = 'view';

public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_LESS => ['field1', 'field2'],
        self::SCENARIO_MORE => ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
    ];
}
```

But still it is returning default fields, no changes occurring any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think scenario only used for validating the data before inserting the data into the table

> The scenario feature is primarily used by validation and massive attribute assignment. You can, however, use it for other purposes. For example, you may declare attribute labels differently based on the current scenario.

But if you want specific fields you should use `fields` method in the model:

```
// explicitly list every field, best used when you want to make sure the changes
// in your DB table or model attributes do not cause your field changes (to keep API backward compatibility).
public function fields()
{
    return [
        // field name is the same as the attribute name
        'id',

        // field name is "email", the corresponding attribute name is "email_address"
        'email' => 'email_address',

        // field name is "name", its value is defined by a PHP callback
        'name' => function () {
            return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
        },
    ];
}

// filter out some fields, best used when you want to inherit the parent implementation
// and blacklist some sensitive fields.
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();

    // remove fields that contain sensitive information
    unset($fields['auth_key'], $fields['password_hash'], $fields['password_reset_token']);

    return $fields;
}
```

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#fields

Comment: can I use scenario for filtering fields in fields() function ?

Comment: why don't you give it a try ? but i don't think so. what you can do is to use `toArray()` function which will give you a array of a model and then use `unset` function to remove particular fields ?